# Why the removeChild() is not working while deleting a list item [Js DOM]?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Here is a [shopping list](https://codepen.io/teddcp/pen/LYVMwor?editors=1111) where you can add few item names and it will display that item. On deleting the item, it will delete that. And finally on clicking the item, it will mark as completed. So creating the item and deleting the item are working fine, but problem occurs while clicking them.

**Problem (occurs while toggling the multiple list item )**

Let's say, you have added are 3 items (xxx,yyy,zzz) and upon clicking them individually, it will toggle them as complete and incomplete.but  *if you have selected the xxx, them zzz and if you click again zzz, it's not working.While if you click the xxx, it will mark as incomplete.*

**Error**

> script.js:91 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on
>   'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
>       at HTMLLIElement.toggleItem

Here is my code.

```js
let input = document.querySelector("#item-name");
let button = document.querySelector("input[type=button]");
let items = document.querySelector(".items");
let ul = document.createElement("ul");
items.appendChild(ul);

function disableFunction() {
  button.disabled = false;
}

function callfun(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    console.log("Enter is pressed...");
    createList();
  }
}

input.addEventListener("input", disableFunction);
button.addEventListener("click", createList);
input.addEventListener("keypress", callfun);

function createList() {
  createList();
}

function createList() {
  if (input.value.length) {
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    li.className = "item";

    let val = input.value;
    if (val.length > 10) {
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(val.slice(0, 7) + "..."));
    } else {
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    }

    let btn = document.createElement("button");
    let i = document.createElement("i");
    i.className = "fa fa-trash fa-2x";
    btn.appendChild(i);
    btn.addEventListener("click", deleteItem);

    //   '<i class="fa fa-trash " aria-hidden="true"></i>';
    //i = document.getElementsByTagName(i);
    li.appendChild(btn);
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value = "";

    li.addEventListener("click", toggleItem);

    console.log("added...");
  }
}

function deleteItem(e) {
  //   console.log(e, e.target.parentElement.parentElement)
  let item = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
  item.style.display = "none";
}

function toggleItem(e) {
  //console.log();
  //console.log(e.target.className.includes("toggle"));
  let liItem = e.target;
  console.log(liItem.textContent);
  console.log(liItem.className.includes("toggle"));

  //if item is completed....
  if (!liItem.className.includes("toggle")) {
    liItem.classList.toggle("toggle");

    let span = document.createElement("span");
    span.className = "completed";
    let i = document.createElement("i");
    i.className = "fa fa-check-circle";
    span.appendChild(i);
    liItem.prepend(span);

    // e.target.innerHTML =
    //   '<span><i class="" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>' +
    //   e.target.innerHTML;
  } else {
    liItem.classList.remove("toggle");
    let spa = document.querySelector(
      `${liItem.tagName.toLowerCase()} .completed`
    );
    console.log(
      document.querySelector(`${liItem.tagName.toLowerCase()} .completed`)
    );
    liItem.removeChild(spa);     // *********LINE 91***********
    console.log(liItem);
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
}

h1 {
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 15px;
}
input[type="text"] {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 15px;
}

input[type="button"] {
  display: block;
  width: 12%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.items {
  margin: 10px;
}

ul {
  background-color: #ef5777;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.toggle {
  background-color: #f53b57;
  text-decoration: wavy;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>ToDo App</title>

    <link
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Shopping List</h1>
      <p>Get it done today</p>

      <input
        type="text"
        name="item-name"
        id="item-name"
        placeholder="Add to the item..."
      />
      <input type="button" value="Add" disabled />

      <div class="items"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: error image in the 3rd row]

Comment: `let spa = document.querySelector...` there is nothing here that enforces that the item you are looking for is a child of the one you're working on.`liItem.querySelector...` would likely work better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) on the QuerySelector() method:

> The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

So when you write:

```
let spa = document.querySelector(
  `${liItem.tagName.toLowerCase()} .completed`
);
```

you get the first element on the DOM that matches your search.
But you are looking for the child element of your liItem with a class of "completed".

**What you want to write:**

```
let spa = liItem.querySelector(".completed");
```

**Extra note:**
the .toggle("aClass") method adds class "aClass" when the element doesn't have it and removes it if it has it already. Therefore you can take the following

```
liItem.classList.toggle("toggle");
```

out of the if-else and apply it anyway.

Comment: Thanks... it was a little thing, but i guess i had sold my brain somewhere..haha..